# Проблема добавления удалённого репозитория

Tags: git

Добрый день. Есть проблема проект у него удалённый репозиторий 1 `https://NAME@bitbucket.org/TUTU/tututu.git` .

Необходимо добавить репозиторий 2 `git remote add origin ssh://repo2/../everfocus.git`

И потом cделать push в мастер `git push origin master`.

После этого получаю ошибку

```
failed to push some refs to репозиторий 1
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing 
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes 
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. 
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Как добавить во второй репозиторий данные?

Что делает git remote add origin repo, могу ли я коммитить после этого в 2 репозитория?

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote add origin
```

Добавляет удалённый репозиторий с именем `origin`. То есть при работе с удалённым репозиторием, например:

`git push origin master`

origin заменяется на Ваш репозиторий `repo1`.

Вы можете сделать 2 удалённых репозитория

```
git remote add origin2 ssh://repo2/../everfocus.git
```

Поменяв имя на origin2. И при необходимости работать со второй репой.

```
git push origin2 master
```

Что касается Вашего первого вопроса. Переключитесь на master и сделайте pull

```
git pull origin
```

Потому

```
git remote add origin2 ssh://repo2/../everfocus.git 

git remote -v
```

должны быть origin и origin2

Comment: Сначала pull и fetch сделать?

Comment: Да, сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: @Вася Вторая проблема уже не раз обсуждалась и разжевывалась: [`failed to push some refs`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=failed%20to%20push%20some%20refs)

Comment: С `git pull` есть хитрая особенность: в данной ситуации он под капотом выполнит `git merge` и сделает петлю в истории коммитов. А ещё этот мерж может внезапно быть конфликтным.

Comment: @NickVolynkin его в данной ситуации лучше не использовать?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать pull если что откатитесь

Comment: @Вася вы сами себе отвечаете? )

Comment: Ник просто объясняет, что git pull не в данной ситации, а в принципе делает merge

Comment: Сделал вроде отработало. Но при git push пишет Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: @NickVolynkin Нет мне просто сказали так сделать и я хотел спросить, как это откатиться  :Р, а тут вдруг не могу отредактировать сообщение

Comment: `git pull` делает `git fetch` и так. Упрощённо `git pull` == `git fetch && git merge`.

Comment: @0andriy Вы правы. Убрал  fetch из ответа